# Visual Studio 2012 source control

Tags: c#, version-control, visual-studio-2012, tfs, repository

I currently use **team foundation server** as a `source control`, however, its database located on my computer, and I want it to be somewhere on the internet, on a small freeware cloud perhaps.

Is there any free `source control` systems, which has build-in **VS2012** support and free repository storage? What are they?

I have googled a bit, but it is a little hard to detect is the system supports internet-hosted repositories and **VS2012** support. I need opinions of real users.

Comment: Hi, if you are referring to Version Control system then you can try this http://git-scm.com/ its free nice and very productive, you'll have to spend a bit time implementing it but on a long run it nice. A brief tutorial is available here http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is [Microsoft's Team Foundation Service](https://tfs.visualstudio.com/), which is hosted TFS and free for small teams.

Comment: I was completely unaware of this! We use TFS at work, but I was in the process of setting up Git at home for my home projects (I was going to use it with Google Drive). But this is a much better plan for me. Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

You might take a look at [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/). Their partner Assembla has cloud-based Perforce depots, free for up to something like 20 users.

- http://www.perforce.com/press/perforce-assembla-partner-deliver-cloud-hosted-solution-accelerates-agile-development
- https://www.assembla.com/repositories/perforce?ref=PerforcePR

Comment: Thanks, but TFS is more familiar.